# Seblod Site form not saving to backend

Tags: php, forms, amazon-ec2, joomla3.0, cck

I created a Forms & Content Types form on both admin and site views. At the admin, it saves as expected but at the site/front end it doesn’t save after clicking submit button?

My form has less than 10 fields using Joomla! 3.4.4 & seblod 3.7.2 installation on Amazon EC2 instance. At first everything was working fine, and then it stopped saving contents from front end to the back end. It doesn’t display any error, it just return a blank empty form.

I want it to save and redirect to a thank you page. The form is [here](http://ec2-52-89-200-207.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/index.php/individual-form).

Note: I don't have this issue on the local server (XAMPP), everything works fine on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

After submitted on your form, no blank error. The thank you message is well displayed.
So it seems your issue is solved, isn't?

Comment: No, issue isn't solved yet? However, I observed when I witched the template from the one am using to "Protostar" default joomla template, the form works fine as expected.